# How to use template with references to script in another repository within Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use a template that's stored in another Git repository in Azure DevOps where that template has a reference to a script also contained within that repository. While I can successfully use the template from the main pipeline it doesn't reference the script the template requires.

Is there some way I can do this please?

The HelloWorld template/script are stored in Azure DevOps Repo 'HelloWorld' in a sub-folder called 'Templates'.

HelloWorld.ps1 script in the same directory as the below template.

```
param($Name)

Write-Host "Hello, $Name!"
```

Template #1 with reference to local script

```yaml
  parameters:
  - name: azureSubscription
    type: string
  - name: name
    type: string
  
  jobs:
  - job: HelloWorld
    displayName: Hello World
    variables:
      name: ${{ parameters.name }}
    steps:
    - task: AzurePowerShell@4
      name: HelloWorld
      displayName: Hello World
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
        scriptType: filePath
        scriptPath: ./HelloWorld.ps1
        azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
        failOnStandardError: true
        scriptArguments:
          -Name "$(name)"
```

Template #2

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: helloworld
      type: git
      name: HelloWorld

stages:
- stage: Variables
  jobs:
  - template: Scripts/hello-world.yml@helloworld
    parameters:
      azureSubscription: 'My Subscription'
      name: 'Billy'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your pipeline has templates in another repository, or if you want to use [multi-repo checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) with a repository that requires a service connection, you must let the system know about that repository. The repository keyword lets you specify an external repository.

You could refer to [Repository resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#repository-resource) and [templates in another repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories) for more details.

Such as in templates repository, we'd expect to find test.yml at the root.

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: templates
steps:
- template: test.yml@templates
```

**Update1**

I update your code and it works, please check it.

The repo HelloWord structure and the repo contain template file and PS1 file

[image]

Template #1 with reference to local script.
Note: I add checkout step to checkout the **HelloWord** and pipeline self repo

```
  parameters:
  - name: azureSubscription
    type: string
  - name: name
    type: string
  
  jobs:
  - job: HelloWorld
    displayName: Hello World
    variables:
      name: ${{ parameters.name }}
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: helloworld
    - task: AzurePowerShell@4
      name: HelloWorld
      displayName: Hello World
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
        scriptType: filePath
        scriptPath: $(build.sourcesdirectory)/Helloworld/Subfolder/HelloWorld.ps1
        azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
        failOnStandardError: true
        scriptArguments:
          -Name "$(name)"
```

In the another repo create yaml build definition.

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: helloworld
      type: git
      name: HelloWorld
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
 
stages:
 
- stage: Variables
  jobs:
  - template: hello-world.yml@helloworld
    parameters:
      azureSubscription: 'My Subscription'
      name: 'Billy'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is how we do it as well.  It's quite unfortunate, though, that you are forced to use a specific name for the repository resource in the root pipeline (i.e. exactly the same name as the one you're using in the checkout step in the template).  In fact, I came across this because I'm looking for a way to find out, from a template, which repository resource (or at least, which branch ref) was used to access the template.

Comment: Same situation than @WillemM. here. It is not elegant the need to hardcode repository name on the repository code.

Answer (score 3):

When you have multiple repositories in your pipeline and you have them when you use template from another repo, they are fetched to their own folders instead of root one. [It seems to be obvious but we need to have this in mind.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path)

> If you have multiple checkout steps in your job, your source code is checked out into directories named after the repositories as a subfolder of s in (Agent.BuildDirectory). If (Agent.BuildDirectory) is C:\agent_work\1 and your repositories are named tools and code, your code is checked out to C:\agent_work\1\s\tools and C:\agent_work\1\s\code.

Thus when you call a script inside a template which is in another repo you may be forced to provide alias name for the repo to properly locate your script.

For instance:

```
trigger: none
pr: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: devops
      type: github
      name: kmadof/devops-templates
      endpoint: kmadof

stages:
- template: templates/start.yaml@devops
  parameters:
    repo: devops-templates
    buildSteps:
      - checkout: self
      - checkout: devops
      - bash: echo Test #Passes
        displayName: succeed
      - bash: echo "Test"
        displayName: succeed
```

I'm passing there repo parameter to use it in my template:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: repo  # defaults for any parameters that aren't specified
  default: ''

steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: ${{ parameters.repo }}/scripts/myscript.ps1
```

You can check code [here](https://github.com/kmadof/devops-templates)

Comment: Does this approach work for two repos exists in two different projects within same DevOps organization?

Answer (score 2):

I will share a more detailed answer to this question for my case.

**Our case:**

[image: tow repo case]

My goal was to build a generic pipeline that will do CI/CD and infra as a code for multiple repositories with the same structured app but with different business logic. In this example I will call one of those repositories as `Repository A` We have `Repostiroy B` which is a template repo with CI/CD steps and it also has multiple bicep files (azure function basic, azure function, and Azure SQL).

**Solutin**

`Repository A`

```yaml
    resources:
      repositories:
        - repository: DevOps
          type: git
          name: Repository/RepositoryB
    
    stages:
      - template: Templates/generic-template.yml@DevOps
        parameters: 
          resourceGroupName: resource-group-name
          azureServiceConnection: service-connection
          bicepFileTemplateName: basic-azure-function
          devOpsResource: DevOps # Pass RepositoryB to template
```

`Repository B`

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: resourceGroupName
  - name: azureServiceConnection
  - name: bicepFileTemplateName
  - name: devOpsResource

stages:
  - stage: CreateEnvironment
    displayName: Provision Bicep ${{ parameters.bicepFileTemplateName }}
    jobs:
      - job: ProvisionBicep
        steps:
          - checkout: ${{ parameters.devOpsResource }}
          - task: AzureCLI@2
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureServiceConnection }}
              scriptType: bash
              scriptLocation: inlineScript
              inlineScript: |
BICEP_TEMPLATE=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Infrastructure/${{ parameters.bicepFileTemplateName }}.bicep
                echo Bicep template path: $BICEP_TEMPLATE
                az deployment group create --resource-group ${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }} --mode Incremental --template-file $BICEP_TEMPLATE
```

Comment: You're missing essential part here - how template repo should locate scripts once checkout is done for repo that is 'self'. In your example 'checkout' will put DevOps repo to RepositoryB folder (repo name used unless you specify explicit path on checkout). However, your inline script uses 'Infrastructure' folder for bicep path (original name for your devops repo I guess). That is the actual answer that is missing - your template repo needs to be explicit when referencing scripts and do so either with FQN or relative to sources directory, and consider templates repo actual checkout folder.

Comment: I'm following same approach described above. But, I'm getting "Git fetch failed with exit code: 128"when my templates repo is another project in the same devops organization. I've tried to configure permissions following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#example---configure-permissions-to-access-another-repo-in-the-same-project-collection But, I'm still getting the same error